# Select value to be shown in combobox list from an ItemsSource class in C# and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm developing an application that use a combobox in wpf. I'm using a class that contain two values `ID` and `Name`, I'm bulding a `list` with this class to be the `ItemsSource` of the combobox, as follow:

**Example.cs**

```
foreach (XmlNode OEM in OEMs)
{
    string OEMname = OEM.Attributes["OEMname"].InnerText;
    int ID = Int32.Parse(OEM.Attributes["ID"].InnerText);

    OEM oem = new OEM { OEMname = OEMname, ID = ID};

    oems.Add(oem);
}

cbxSelOEM.ItemsSource = oems;
```

My problem is the value shown in the combobox, instead of show the OEMname value they show other name, I believe that is the object name in the list. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try `cbxSelOEM.DisplayName = "OEMname";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically the `ToString()` of objects is shown at the `ComboBox`. To show the `OEMname` simply set the [DisplayMemberPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath(v=vs.110).aspx) like

```
cbxSelOEM.DisplayMemberPath = "OEMname";
```